# Improving our javascript error reporting

Tags: javascript, ios, error-handling, jquery-mobile, cordova

So right now we have some generic code to report errors either from our code or third party code.  Our project is a JQM/Phonegap project for iOS.  What is happening is we pretty much always get the same useless error... TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function... with no line number or other helpful information.  Is there a way I could change the code to maybe get WHAT is undefined or WHERE it is?

```
window.onerror = function myErrorHandler(errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
    //Handle errors not in a jquery event handler
    //DebugMessage(errorMSg + " "+ url + " " + lineNumber);
    var ex = new Error(errorMsg, url, lineNumber);
    HandleError(ex, "window.onerror");  
        //HandleError sends the error object to 
        //a webservice to log the error.
    return true;
};
```

Any tips on debugging javascript errors would help as well.

Comment: I have the same problem. It looks like a bug of UIWebView, because when I run the same code on safari/chrome, the lineNumber is defined. We should report the bug to Apple : https://bugreport.apple.com - the more we fill report on this bug, the more it will become important (it's not possible to vote for a bug, so Apple team prioritize bug report counting the number of duplicate).

Comment: Not sure if this works for mobile but I have used this in the past: https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Error-Handler-Plugin also turning on debug mode in Mobile Safari and using console.log('error message'); works as well

Comment: Looking at the code for the plugin, it does the same thing as the code above (replaces onerror with code the emails/logs the error).  So I'll still get TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function, line: undefined.  I'll fill out the bug report while I continue looking for a way to get around the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In recent months, browsers have extended the signature of `window.onerror` to provide more information.

```
window.onerror = function(msg, file, line, col, error) {

  // backwards compat
  if (!error) {
    error = new Error(msg);
  }

  // send error to your logger

}
```

This should give you a lot more information. But there are still things where you need better context. You should check out some third-party tools for this like [TrackJS](https://trackjs.com) that automatically give you this, plus extra information on how the error occurred.

Disclaimer: I am one of the original authors of TrackJS, so I know a bunch about JavaScript errors :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of [Ripple](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc)? It is a mobile emulator for Chrome designed for testing PhoneGap applications.

That might help you find your errors before you debug on the devices.